# FULLTEXT indexes in MariaDB 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB documentation says that FULLTEXT indexes for InnoDB are supported since version 10.0.5 (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/optimization-and-indexes/full-text-indexes/fulltext-index-overview/)

I recently installed MariaDB 10.0.13 and tried to convert a MyISAM table to InnoDB, like so:

```
MariaDB [(test)]> ALTER TABLE field_values ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But ran into this error:

```
ERROR 1214 (HY000): The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

Here's the `SHOW INDEXES` query for my table:

```
MariaDB [(test)]> show indexes in  field_values;
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| field_values |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | productid   | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| field_values |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | fieldid     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| field_values |          1 | value    |            1 | value       | NULL      |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

MariaDB documentation states these indexes that can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns. So here's a `DESCRIBE TABLE` for my table:

```
MariaDB [(test)]> describe  field_values ;
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| productid | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| fieldid   | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| value     | char(255) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The field in question (`value`) is supported, being of type `CHAR`.

Finally, here's my MariaDB version:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.13-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

So, according to MariaDB documentation at least, this operation should be supported and yet I'm seeing an error. Do I have to do anything else to enable FULLTEXT indexes in MariaDB 10.0.13?

Comment: I did a re-install and it seems to be working as expected. I'm gonna chalk this to user/installation error. I was trying to do this: MySQL 5.1 -> MariaDB 5.5 -> MariaDB 10.0 and this resource helped - https://mariadb.com/blog/upgrading-mysql-51-mariadb-100-centos-6

Comment: The above link is broken. New one here https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/upgrading-mysql-5-1-to-mariadb-10-0-on-centos-6/

Answer (score 6):

So after upgrading MariaDB to 10.0.14 I added the Fulltext Indexes manually and that just worked perfectly. Maybe there is a conversion error from MyIsam Index to the XtraDB/InnoDB Index.

But what should've worked fine is:

1. Delete your Indexes from MyIsam
2. Upgrade MariaDB to 10.x
3. Switch MyIsam to InnoDB
4. Add Indexes manually

You can add a Fulltext Index in MariaDB like this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `ft_column_name` (column_name);
```

After that you should be able to use your queries as expected.

Comment: i am trying to run this query
`ALTER TABLE video ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_index (title,tags) WITH PARSER ngram;
`
but mariaDB says function ngram is not defined? any help regarding this i need ngram for korean language

Comment: See the comments here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-overview/ (on the bottom)